# SQL query output as a dataframe in R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I am very new to R. I wanted to use a sql query to get data with R. (I am using athena but I think this doesn't matter).

```
con <- dbConnect(RAthena::athena(),
                 s3_staging_dir = 's3://bla/bla/'
                 )

df <- tbl(con, sql("SELECT * FROM db.my_data"))
```

My problem is that `df` is not a dataframe. So when I do `names(df)` for example I don't get the columns (as I would with Python) but get `'src''ops'` instead. I don't know what this means (these are not columns). How can I convert this `df` so it is a dataframe in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `dbGetQuery` from package `DBI`

From documentation:

> Description Returns the result of a query as a data frame.
> dbGetQuery() comes with a default implementation (which should work
> with most backends) that calls dbSendQuery(), then dbFetch(), ensuring
> that the result is always free-d by dbClearResult().

Implemantation from your example:

```
df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM db.my_data")
```